# Putting data from several trials into a table

Tags: list-manipulation, data, grid-layouts

I need this data to go into a table nearly exactly in this format, but i need the left most column to say trial 1, trial 2, trial 3, trial 4, then the data to go horizontally across for each trial like I have here.  I can't figure out how to do it with Grid or Table ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

@Syed's answer is excellent, and if you just need a purely textual result gridded into a table, then that's a streamlined way to go. However, I feel like you're on the brink of needing to know about Association and Dataset. Simply prepending the label to each list will impede any further processing/analyzing/querying. Let's make your data into a Dataset.

We need some data to play with, and we'll give it a name:

```
peakDataRaw = RandomReal[{20, 80}, {4, 7}]
```

To start, I'll assume that the data is columnar, and so here are some arbitrary column labels (make your own as needed):

```
peakDataColumnar = AssociationThread[CharacterRange["a", "g"], #] & /@ peakDataRaw
(*{<|"a" -> 32.8626, "b" -> 59.5233, ...etc..., "g" -> 78.2456|>, ...etc...}*)
```

Now let's add row labels:

```
peakAssocColumnar = 
  MapIndexed[
    ToString[StringForm["Trial ``", #2[[1]]]] -> #1 &, 
    peakDataColumnar]
(*{"Trial 1" -> <|"a" -> 28.296, ...etc...|>, "Trial 2" -> <|...etc...|>, ...etc...}*)
```

Now, we can turn this into a Dataset (need to wrap in an Association first):

```
peakDataset = Dataset@Association@peakAssocColumnar
(*should see a nice tabular view*)
```

You can also make a Dataset without the column labels:

```
Dataset[peakAssocRaw]
```

The view you get here won't be what I think you want, but it'll have row labels and will be a query-able/manipulatable Dataset.

Comment: Very nice!  The step-by-step approach is appreciated; this makes a useful tutorial.